Why don't my slash commands, bot join/remove events and buttons aren't working in this discord bot?
this code has worked perfectly fine but i reinstalled py-cord and discord and now theres a bunch of errors with some stuff, ive managed to fix most of it but the command issue isnt really working.
This is the full code:
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from typing import Final
import traceback
from discord.ui import Button, View

whitelist = {
     "mystic27" : 595287696000155729,
}

intents = discord.Intents.default()

intents.messages = True #NOQA
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='%', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Goldie is ready")

@bot.slash_command(name = "helpinvites", description = "More indepth help with Invite Commands")
async def helpinvite(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Invite Commands")
    embed.add_field(name="Invites: ", value="> ```/invites``` -> Tracks all active invites the server has.\n> ```/deleteinv inv: Invite``` -> Deletes an invite.\n> ```/trackinvites``` -> Enables/disabled where or who a user was invited from.")
    embed.add_field(name = "Logs: ",value="> ```/logjoin``` -> Logs user join in a certain channel.\n> ```/logleave``` -> Logs user leave in a certain channel.")
    await ctx.respond(embed=embed)

@bot.slash_command(name = "helpmoderation",description = "More indepth help with Moderation commands")
async def helpmoderation(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title = "Moderation Commands")
    embed.add_field(name = "Moderation: ",value="> ```/mute``` -> Mutes user.\n> ```/warn``` -> Warns user.\n> ```/ban``` -> Bans user.")
    embed.add_field(name = "Chat moderation",value= "> ```/banword(s)``` -> Bans certain words.\n> ```/pg``` -> Goes completely PG (Reversible)")
    await ctx.respond(embed=embed) 


@bot.slash_command(name = "helputility",description = "Help with Utility commands")
async def helputil(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Utility Commands")
    embed.add_field(name="Invites: ", value="> ```/invites``` -> Tracks all active invites the server has.\n> ```/deleteinv inv: Invite``` -> Deletes an invite.\n> ```/trackinvites``` -> Enables/disabled where or who a user was invited from.")
    embed.add_field(name = "Moderation: ",value="> ```/mute``` -> Mutes user.\n> ```/warn``` -> Warns user.\n> ```/ban``` -> Bans user.\n>```/banword(s)``` -> Bans certain words.\n> ```/pg``` -> Goes completely PG (Reversible)")
    button = Button(label = "Invite Help", style=discord.ButtonStyle.secondary,emoji="")

    async def button_callback(self,button,interaction):
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content = helpinvite(),view = self)

    button.callback = button_callback

    view = View()
    view.add_item(button)
        
    await ctx.respond(embed=embed,view=View)

@bot.slash_command(name = "logjoin", description = "Logs user join in a specified channel")
async def logjoin(ctx,channel):
    global channellogkoin,logjoinaccess
    channellogkoin = await bot.fetch_channel(channel)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Joins are enabled ✔!",description=f"Completed in {bot.latency}")
    logjoinaccess = True
    await ctx.respond(embed=embed)
    
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{member} joined. ✔",description=f"Completed in {bot.latency}")
    if logjoinaccess == True:
        await channellogkoin.send(embed=embed)

@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{member} left. ❌",description=f"Completed in {bot.latency}")
    await channellogkoin.send(embed=embed)



@bot.slash_command(name = "ping",guild = 927168781275525210)
async def ping(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Pong!",description=f"Completed in {bot.latency}")
    await ctx.respond(embed=embed)

@bot.slash_command(name="log",description = "Log a message in a channel")
async def log(ctx,channel,*contents: str):
        channel = await bot.fetch_channel(channel)
        await channel.send(f"```{contents} logged by <@{ctx.message.author.id}>```")
        await ctx.respond("Command Completed")

@bot.slash_command(name="whois",description = "A short background check on a user.")
async def userinfo(ctx: commands.Context, user: discord.User):
    user_id = user.id
    username = user.name
    await ctx.respond(f'User found: {user_id} -- {username}')


@bot.command()
async def updated(ctx):     
    await ctx.send("Goldie version 1.0")

@bot.slash_command(name = "menu", guild = 927168781275525210, description = "Menu for Goldie")
async def menu(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title = "Main Menu", description = "Welcome to Goldie!\nI am a Multi-Utility bot and can help with building your server and more!")
    embed.add_field(name="Basic Utility: ", value=" > - ```/ping```")
    embed.add_field(name = "Advanced Permissions: ", value="> - ```/goldaccess```")
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Support Server - https://discord.gg/Goldie | Completed in {bot.latency}")
    await ctx.respond(embed=embed)


load_dotenv()

TOKEN: Final[str] = os.getenv('discord_token')

def main() -> None:
    bot.run(TOKEN)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()



ps - Any commands or websites mentioned in the code don't work and added for fun tbh. Also, my buttons in the command "helpinvites" don't work and the bot join event/ bot remove event don't work either so would help to get some more help on those too please!
I have tried searching up solutions, looking at other peoples problems and try reinstalling again. I do not know what has just happened after reinstalling.
This error pops up for slash commands: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'slash_command'
There is no error for the bot join/remove event it simply does not work and I would attach error for buttons however I can't run the code as commands don't work.

Are you sure that you have py-cord installed and not discord.py?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Looking at the docs, it seems like you can just say:
@bot.command(description=“desc”)
def commandname(ctx):
    # implementation 

slash_command may not be supported anymore or something. Sadly, I don’t use pycord so I can’t really help with embeds.
EDIT: This isn’t correct

Isn't that for normal commands? I am still learning how to code discord bots properly so I may be wrong, but normal commands were shifted to slash commands some time ago so I don't really know, and many recent posts still use slash_command

I’m just going by the 2 google searches I tried (one for ‘slash_command’ and one for pycord slash commands) and I got this page from the docs, which says slash commands just use command

This is not true. In the most recent version of pycord slash_command is a part of bot. See here

Sorry, my bad. I though it was right.
